# How to get rid of the date and time that appears before every NSLog statement in the console

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nslog

I use NSLog in my application. And I'd like to get rid of the annoying beginning of each string: "2009-07-01 21:11:06.508 MyApp[1191:207]".

Is there a way to do so? Probably another logging function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Read these:

- https://github.com/davislg/QuietLog
- https://web.archive.org/web/20140924195139/http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/different-nslog

It's a Github project called "QuietLog", originally from our CocoaHeads site, that explains how to create a `QuietLog` function that does what you're describing.  It also shows how to wrap QuietLog into a macro called LocationLog so that it'll print out the file name and line number where you've got the log statement.  I use it in all of my projects, and I don't lose stray "NSLog" statements anymore.

Comment: +1 Dang, I was about to post the same thing. I *wrote* that wiki page... ;-)

Comment: And you got it from the Borkware Quickies, so it all evens out.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

This preprocessor macro is easy to implement and you don't have to change any of your current `NSLog` statements:

```
#define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

It works completely like `NSLog` without all the extra things before the message.

I original found this on another SO question, but I can't find it now.

Answer (score 1):

I like being able to use objective-C objects for format strings and arguments, so I re-wrote NSLog() and added it to my utilities.

```
+ (void)myLog:(NSString *)formatString, ...
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, formatString);
    NSString* output = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatString arguments:args];
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", [output UTF8String]);
    [output release];
    va_end(args);
}
```

Comment: If you read the link Dave linked to, you'd see that this is what we do, except we also handle %% entities in the format string.

Comment: Quinn, I didn't see that post until after I posted my answer.  Also there is something to be said for having the answer up front and not having to follow an external link.

Comment: No worries. (SO will usually tell you when other answers have ben posted, but overlap is quite normal.) You're right, sometimes it's nice to have the code right in the answer. However, once it passes a certain size, or in this case when the wiki page is likely to change (which it has since Dave's post) it may be better to link.

Comment: Also, note that this is a slightly different approach by creating a class method (which is called on that class) rather than a C function like NSLog() that can be used anywhere. Just depends on what the asker would prefer, and the scope of usage.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [CFShow()](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFTypeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFShow)?

Comment: (Added link to docs) I wasn't aware of that function, good to know. However, it's not a drop-in replacement, since you'd have to have an NSString* to cast as a CFStringRef. Still, one could easily define a macro or function to wrap CFShow()...

Comment: Unfortunately, CFShow has some very weird behaviour in Leopard which it erroneously hard wraps lines unreadably.  For Leopard, its definitely best to avoid CFShow altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You could print to sdterr:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Your message");
```

**Edit:** Check out [this implementation](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2009/03/23/114/) by Karl Kraft

Comment: That requires (converting to) a C string, and a format string with %@ in it won't work. It's not a bad idea, but using it directly is not a drop-in replacement for NSLog().

Comment: True, you should wrap it in a function with varargs. I use one from Karl Kraft http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2009/03/23/114/

Comment: I like the debug on/off switch in his approach, but he also doesn't %%  escapes (admittedly rare, but problematic when they occur).